# Service manager working in windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have develop a window service. I am just confused about that how SCM is working for that service. What are the parametrs SCM saving against a simple service.

Comment: in what manner? you've built a service, you've install it, windows services then can be viewed with parameters, states etc.. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I have develop a Test service. Having a timer in it. OnTimer event I am just logging a message at file. I have read about Service Control Manager but I cannot undertsand how it properly working. The question in my mind are. when we install a service how SCM save the related parametrs. Can any please tell me a brief working of SCM.

Comment: the two arent really related, scm is more about starting and stopping your service, not what your service does.. If your service has parameters, it puts it in the parameters line - which intern is in the registry.. go look

Comment: thanks bug finder for clearing my point